# How to render Server control Client ID in html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myfunc(param1, param2, param3)
{
//my stuff
}

</script>

<asp:Textbox id="txt" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>
<asp:Button id="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick="myfunc(textboxclientid, 'secondvalue', 'thirdvalue')">
```

How can i send clientID of textbox to my javascript function from button onclientclick

Comment: are you want to send textbox's client id or button's client id on 'onclientclick' event in javascript?

Comment: yes i want to send clientid on clientclickevent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function myfunc(param1, param2, param3)
{
var id = document.getElementById("ctrlname").value;
}
```

and you can also use

```
 var txtUsernameID = '<%= txtboxname.ClientID %>';
```

hope this will help you

**Updated answer**

you have to try this

```
<input type="text" id="txtFirstName" runat="server" class="textReg"
onclientclick="javascript:myfunc(<%=txtFirstName%>,'imgFirstNameS','imgFirstNameE');" />`
```

Java script function

```
function myfunc(control, success, error) {
control = document.getElementById('<%='+control+'.ClientID %>');
}
```

Hope this will your proper solution

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged it jQuery you can use a jQuery selector:

```
<script>
  $("#<%=btn.ClientID%>").click(function() {
    //my stuff
  });
</script>
```

Or if you still want to use `OnClientClick`:

```
<asp:Button id="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick="myfunc(this, 'secondvalue', 'thirdvalue')">
<script>
  function myfunc(btn, val1, val2) {
    var buttonRef = $(btn);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I have been using the first option you mentioned in my javascript files.

Comment: You can also use `$('[id$=btn]')` selector to select the element

Comment: @Sushanth-- I've done that myself on occasion so I can use it in external js files. Probably worth prefixing the ID with the ASP.net sepearator `_` if required or else you could capture `id="abtn"`, etc. too

Comment: i need to send the textbox id not the button's

Comment: The same solution applies. `$("#<%=txt.ClientID%>")` will give you an instance of the TextBox. `$(btn).prev("input:text")` inside `myfunc` too. Or any number of jQuery selectors.

Comment: brother i need to render it in the html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly

```
OnClientClick="
```

supposed to be

```
onclick="
```

You can use `this.id` that is the client id of the element

```
onclick="myfunc(this.id,
```

Comment: OnClientClick is the property of the asp:button control.

Comment: i need to send the textbox id not the button's

Comment: You can directly access in inside the function using either `$('[id$=txt]').attr('id')` or `$('<%= txt.clientId %>').attr('id')`

Comment: i need to render the id in html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick="myfunc($("#<%=txt.ClientID%>"), 'secondvalue', 'thirdvalue')` . Another point is you can  easily do this by `jquery` as well

Comment: i need to send the textbox id not the button

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
document.getElementById('<%= NameOfElement.ClientID%>');
```

ex:

```
document.getElementById('<%= txt.ClientID%>');
```